# Compare two json files using jq or any other tools in bash

Tags: json, bash, jq, containment, elaboration

I want to compare two json files to see if one can be extracted from the other one.

**P1 (p1.json)**

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "keys": ["key1","key2"],
  "body": {
    "height": "180cm",
    "wight": "70kg"
  },
  "name": "Alex"
}
```

**P2 (p2.json)**

```
{
  "id": 12,
  "keys": ["key2","key1"],
  "body": {
    "height": "180cm"
  }
}
```

As it can be seen **P2** is not completely equal to **P1** but it can be extracted from **P1** (It provides less data about the same person but the data is correct).

**Expected behavior:**

```
p1 extends p2 --> true
p2 extends p1 --> false
```

**Notes**
- An array cannot be extracted from the same array with some additional elements

Answer (score 2):

The following definition of `extends/1` uses a purely object-based definition of extension (in particular, it does not sort arrays).  The OP requirements regarding arrays are unclear to me, but a variant definition is offered in the following section.

```
# Usage: $in | extends($b) iff $in contains $b in an object-based sense
def extends($b):
  # Handle the case that both are objects:
  def objextends($x):
    . as $in | all($x|keys[]; . as $k | $in[$k] | extends($x[$k]));
  # Handle the case that both are arrays:
  def arrayextends($x):
    . as $in
    | length == ($x|length) and
        all( range(0;length); . as $i | $in[$i] | extends($x[$i]));

  if . == $b then true
  else . as $in
  | type as $intype
  | ($intype == ($b|type)) and
      (($intype == "object" and objextends($b)) or
       ($intype == "array" and arrayextends($b)))
```

end;

Examples:

```
{a:{a:1,b:2}, b:2} | extends({a:{a:1}}) # true

{a:{a:1,b:2}, b:2} | extends({a:{a:2}}) # false

{a:{a:1,b:2}, b:[{x:1,y:2}]} | extends({a:{a:2}, b:[{x:1}]}) # true
```

#### Alternative definition

The following definition sorts arrays and is sufficiently generous to handle the given example:

```
# Usage: $in | extends2($b) iff $in contains $b in a way which ignores the order of array elements
def extends2($b):
  # Both are objects
  def objextends($x):
    . as $in | all($x|keys[]; . as $k | $in[$k] | extends($x[$k]));

  def arrayextends($x): ($x|sort) - sort == [];

  if . == $b then true
  else . as $in
  | type as $intype
  | ($intype == ($b|type)) and
      (($intype == "object" and objextends($b)) or
       ($intype == "array"  and arrayextends($b)))
  end;
```

With $P1 and $P2 as shown:

```
  $P1 | extends2($P2) # yields true
```

Comment: Programming in `jq` seems bordering on the perverse. Gotta learn me some of that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are no duplicates in any subarrays then you could use this approach which computes the difference between sets of `[path,value]` pairs returned from [tostream](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostream) replacing array indices with `null`:

```
def details:[
     tostream
   | select(length==2) as [$p,$v]
   | [$p|map(if type=="number" then null else . end),$v]
];

def extends(a;b): (b|details) - (a|details) == [];
```

If `P1` and `P2` are functions returning the sample data

```
def P1: {
    "id": 12,
    "keys": ["key1","key2"],
    "body": {
      "height": "180cm",
      "wight": "70kg"
    },
    "name": "Alex"
  }
;

def P2: {
    "id": 12,
    "keys": ["key2","key1"],
    "body": {
      "height": "180cm"
    }
  }
;
```

then

```
  extends(P1;P2)  # returns true
, extends(P2;P1)  # returns false
```

In the presence of duplicates the result is less clear. e.g.

```
  extends(["a","b","b"];["a","a","b"])  # returns true
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##lVFNb4MwDL3zK6ysB5BgarhsAnHYP@COOITiFtYQGDFr0ehfHwvd@DjsUkuR4/eerZf4/WMcwUSOR3NIlFIHiQVzUK2pRVHNyAAaJR7IlqhOVESR74DQkOwad/eZrioDDJVo7PII1DcYRUx1VYYtAypQgeqkBJQa4RlQ5c7SnIYWWLMfvJIhtS3CzAnAzoY/gw54YIu1iiJIlsalO@YBfC0vYWXOAuC@uyJn7LXBkunCmTsln6UbQVbnPdsOMViB5akggzL@uj9UzN2Sl5l72Z9PbGFum5lKVDgp3iReZ8XtnkNrte4/YN3/tc4ftr76@88HLN8f8zA2a4YnoLbDO@mupB/G/E4ehdnnOH7XDZW10qPnTVv2StV0ZIpWXLy6I1P8AA)